# Right Click with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, right-click

How do I preform a right click with applescript?

Comment: is there something in particular you are try to do with an application what is the over goal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use my MouseTools unix executable found [here](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html). At the bottom of the web page are examples and applescripts that show how to use it.

Comment: Glad you like it SSteve. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a third party macro program like Keyboard Maestro or Quickeys.  Quickeys would be my suggestion as it's very, very nice for automation and does a lot more including text substitution.  It's also very scriptable itself via Applescript.  So you can setup a macro to control a non-scriptable application and then call that via Applescript.

With Quickeys you could do a right click by setting up a macro to do it and then call it via.

```
tell application "QuicKeys"
   play shortcut named "myclick"
end tell
```

There used to be a few OSAX for Applescript that were free that did this but they are no longer supported and I think were never ported to Intel.